# How can I list all classes in PHP and display custom values from them?

Tags: php

I have 2 classes with the following code: Class1.class.php and Class2.class.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
class Class1 {
    public $version = "1.0.0";
    public $vendor = "somevendorname";
    public $name = __CLASS__;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function _Version()
    {
        return $this->version;
    }

    public function _Name()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function _Vendor()
    {
        return $this->vendor;
    }
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
namespace App;
class Class2
{
    public function _LoadVendors()
    {
        $dirs = [];
        $handle = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor');
        $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'autoload.php');
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if (!in_array($file, $blacklist))
            {
                $dirs[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
        return $dirs;
    }
}
?>
```

autoload.php is a file which loads everything at once and i want to make an array which contains Name, Version and Vendor from all the classes.

autoload.php contains the following code:

```
<?php
include 'classes/Class1.class.php';
include 'classes/Class2.class.php';

$autoload = new App\Class2();
?>
```

and the following code is on my index.php file:

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
foreach($autoload->_LoadVendors() as $vendor)
{
    //here what to do?
}
?>
```

In the comment //here what to do, I can't deal with making an array which handles classname and calling it's variables as example:

```
$myarray = array(
    Class1 = array(
        Name => Class1->_Name(),
        Vendor => Class1->_Vendor(),
        Version => Class1->_Version()
    ),
    Class2 = array(
        Name => Class2->_Name(),
        Vendor => Class2->_Vendor(),
        Version => Class2->_Version()
    )
);
```

As you can see i'm using namespaces and i can't deal properly with them. I tried with echo $vendor->_Name(); but it shows that classname is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your, approach is quite wrong, you are trying to mimic spl_auto_register
the wrong way...

but lets assume this is your way:

loading a class file is not the same as "calling" the class:

your code should look like this :

```
 namespace App;
   class Class1 {

    const Version = "1.0.0";
    const Vendor = "somevendorname";
    const ClassName ="Your Class Name"; <--- you can't use __CLASS___ 

     function __construct() {

          }  etc....

     }
```

and your index.php

```
      include 'vendor/autoload.php';
        $classList = [];
      foreach($autoload->_LoadVendors() as $vendor)
      {
         $classList[] = array('name'=>$vendor::Vendor,
                      'Version'::$Vendor::Version,
                      'Name'=>$Vendor::Name);
      }
```